# In shiny, is it possible to update input selection based on client web browser input?

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I want to design an app that will be able to optionally take inputs also from the client web browser. So if my URL is `www.something.com?text=myValue` I know that I can store `myValue` with

```
query <- parseQueryString(session$clientData$url_search) 
if (!is.null(query[['text']])) {
      query_text <<- query[['text']]
}
```

This simple app takes the value from a `selectizeInput` and renders it in a `textOutput`.

```
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(

  fluidRow(column(6, selectizeInput("in1", 
                                     label = NULL, 
                                     choices = c("alpha",
                                                 "beta",
                                                 "gamma"),
                                     selected = "beta")),
           column(6, textOutput('out1')))


))
```

Still I want to update the selection of my `selectizeInput` *if* any value is passed from the client web browser.

So I do this on the server side

```
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  query_text <- character()

  observe({
    query <- parseQueryString(session$clientData$url_search)
    if (!is.null(query[['text']])) {
      query_text <<- query[['text']]
      updateSelectizeInput('in1',
                           label = NULL,
                           choices = c("alpha","beta", "gamma"),
                           selected = query_text,
                           server = TRUE)
    }
  })

  output$out1 <- renderText({
    input$in1
  })

})
```

If I launch my app with

```
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I don't get any error and I am able to modify the `textOutput` by manually selecting a value from the `selectizeInput`. BUT when I try to pass a value with my browser, thus triggering my `if` condition, I get this error

```
Warning: Error in $: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
Stack trace (innermost first):
    56: dropNulls
    55: updateSelectizeInput
    54: observerFunc [/Users/francesco/Desktop/Tests/testy/app.R#35]
     1: runApp
ERROR: [on_request_read] connection reset by peer
```

Answer (score 1):

What you did just works except for the fact that... the first argument of `updateSelectizeInput` is the `session` object, and not the element id. See `?updateSelectizeInput`. So, just add it:

```
updateSelectizeInput(session, 'in1',
                           label = NULL,
                           choices = c("alpha","beta", "gamma"),
                           selected = query_text,
                           server = TRUE)
```

and it will work.